# Blurry Chrome's window after waking up from hibernation

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, hibernate

This is, how my Chrome's window looked like directly after waking up my computer from hibernation:

[image]

It lasted about 3-5 seconds and then everything went back to normal.

Screen overlay looks exactly like the one, when you hover your mouse pointer to the right-bottom corner. But in normal situation, actual contents of window are hidden / invisible and you can only see borders of windows below an overlay. Here you can cleary see blurry contents below an overlay.

Is this some kind of bug or by design?

This has happened to me a few times, but today I managed to catch this. I don't remember, if this happens on Chrome only or if in general across my Windows 7.